How to remove previous route in Flutter?
I have a simple code.
routes: {
        '/' : (context) => KartSelectorScreen(onKartSelected: _updateKartNumber, karts: karts),
        '/car_info': (context) => KartInfoScreen(currentKart: getSelectedCar(initialKartNumber)),
        '/car_ride': (context) => KartRideScreen(kartNumber: initialKartNumber),
      },
      initialRoute: widget.initialKartNumber == null ? '/' : '/car_info',

I have a problem when I launch the application and if there is a car number, it goes to the address /car_info. But when you click the go back button, it goes back to /. At the same time, there is such a line at /car_info
 void checkLongPress() {
    if (isBottomRightPush && isTopRightPush) {
      _resetKartNumber();
      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
      context,
      '/',
      (route) => false, 
      );
    }
  }

With this code, the button just closes the application, as I need it. How to implement this in initialroute?
I am trying this and it not working
onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
  WidgetBuilder builder;
  switch (settings.name) {
    case '/':
      builder = (BuildContext _) => KartSelectorScreen(onKartSelected: _updateKartNumber, karts: karts);
      break;
    case '/car_info':
      builder = (BuildContext _) => KartInfoScreen(currentKart: getSelectedCar(initialKartNumber));
      break;
    case '/car_ride':
      builder = (BuildContext _) => KartRideScreen(kartNumber: initialKartNumber);
      break;
    default:
      throw Exception('Invalid route: ${settings.name}');
  }
  return MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: builder,
    settings: settings,
    maintainState: false, 
  );


Try this code, hope it works
case '/car_info':
      if (initialKartNumber != null) {
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext _) => KartInfoScreen(currentKart: getSelectedCar(initialKartNumber)),
          settings: settings,
          maintainState: false,
        ).then((_) => Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, '/', (route) => false));
      } else {
        builder = (BuildContext _) => KartInfoScreen(currentKart: getSelectedCar(initialKartNumber));
      }
      break;


I have error. The method 'then' isn't defined for the type 'MaterialPageRoute'. And one more clarification, I need that when initalKartNumber != null, he went to /car_info and when he clicked the back button, he did not have a path / back. That is, to return to / it was possible only through the check Long Press method so that when he clicked the back button, he did not have anything in the tree.
